# How to create an SSL AWS API Gateway endpoint with custom domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, aws-api-gateway

I've managed to set up a custom domain for my api gateway end point but the https thing is crossed out in red. I generated my certificates from Letsencrypt for *.mydomain.com

The API gateway end point is api.mydomain.com/prod/

Anyway to use Cloudfront or ACM to generate the SSL for API Gateway endpoint? Must I use letsencrypt?

I find it odd that there's no drop in support for adding custom domains via route53 and api gateway (everytime I select alias before adding CNAME record, the cloudfront endpoint doesnt appear)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> > but the https thing is crossed out in red

I'm not sure what you mean by that.  Is it red in your browser's URL bar?

> > Anyway to use Cloudfront or ACM to generate the SSL for API Gateway endpoint?

Not currently.  We're looking into integrating API Gateway with Amazon Certificate Manager (ACM), but we don't yet have an estimated delivery date.

> > everytime I select alias before adding CNAME record, the cloudfront endpoint doesnt appear

We're hoping to address that when we add the ACM integration.

Comment: yes. https is in red and its crossed out in chrome. what can I do in order to make my `https://api.mydomain.com` point to my api gateway endpoint? Outstanding support btw! Now this is some dedication.

Comment: Is "api.mydomain.com" just a placeholder, or is that literally the domain name you're trying to set-up?  If that is your domain name, then do you actually own the "mydomain.com" domain?  Assuming you own it, you have to add a CNAME record via your DNS provider to map api.mydomain.com to the domain name of the CloudFront distribution that API Gateway display at the top of the Custom Domain page.

Comment: Just adding a custom domain entry in API Gateway doesn't acquire the domain for you.  You still have to buy the name via a domain registar and you need a DNS provider to serve DNS request for your domain name. Assuming you own mydomain.com, you have to add a CNAME record via your DNS provider to map api.mydomain.com to the domain name of the CloudFront distribution that API Gateway displays at the top of the Custom Domain page.

Comment: yeah I own the domain, and I added the cname, it's working. However, I generated the SSL from letsencrypt and for some reason I guess I screwed up the copy & pasting part...and it's impossible to add non SSL domains to api gateway so....the SSL certificate was set to *.mydomain.com so I'm not sure why api.mydomain.com isn't working.

Comment: An SSL certificate for *.mydomain.com should work with the custom domain name api.mydomain.com.  I tried to investigate further, but the name api.mydomain.com does not currently resolve via DNS.  Is your CNAME still in place?

Comment: @MikeDatAWS Was there ever a solid solution to this issue? We will be facing the same situation in a short time, and I would greatly appreciate if you could tell me if there is a general solution right now.

Comment: We never determined what this issue was.  There are thousands of customer successfully using custom domain names with API Gateway, including customers using wildcard certificates (*.something).

Comment: Not everyone wants to use stages, not everyone wants or needs to wait 45 minutes just so they can have a custom domain name.